# Add Wordpress Registered User in a Google Form answers Spreadsheet

Tags: wordpress, forms, google-sheets, user-input, google-forms

It´s possible add a Wordpress registered user to Google form answers into a column without input on form? I need to have several answers from same user and get from all in same spreadsheet.

If I run this in console I get put my email on first empty cell, but when I submit form it doesn't work.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var ssID = 'abcdefg';
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);

ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1"));

var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
   if(data[i][0].trim() == ""){
      var rango = 'A'.concat(i+1);
      ss.getRange(rango).setValue(email);
   break;}
}
}
```

---

¿Es posible asociar el usuario de WP a las respuestas del formulario sin tener que pedir que escriba su email? Quiero poder tener varias respuestas de un mismo usuario y tener las de todos los usuarios en la misma hoja de respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

The method: [`Session.getActiveUser()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser) requires ***user*** authorization.

The method `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` returns an empty string if the user has not authorized your app with the scope:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`

However, these restrictions generally do not apply if:

1. The developer runs the script themselves
   or
2. The developer belongs to the same G Suite domain as the user.